# What Does it Mean for a Subgroup to Have a Finite Index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, quotient-group

I want to understand the concept of groups that have a finite index intuitively.

---

Suppose $H$ and $K$ are infinite subgroups, $H \subset K$,  and $[ K:H ]$ is finite.

Intuitivelly, does this mean there are a finite set of elements in $H$ that are not in $K$? Since each element of $H$ not in $K$ will map to a coset of $K/H$?

Or does it mean there could be infinite elements in $H$ that are not in $K$, but quotient map $ K \rightarrow K/H$ is not injective, and there are only a finite number of cosets?

Comment: Maybe it helps to look at concrete examples, e.g. $H = 5 \mathbb{Z}$ and $K = \mathbb{Z}$. Looking at $K$ mod $H$ there are only finitely many elements, i.e. if we try to distinguish elements of $K$ in $H$, we only see finitely many elements.

Comment: The latter, and it should be $K/H$, not $H/K$

Comment: Infinitely many elements, finitely many equivalence classes of elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $H$ is a subgroup (not necessarily a *normal* subgroup) of $K$, we can form a partition of $K$ by [left cosets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset#Index_of_a_subgroup) $kH = \{kh \mid h\in H \}$ using elements $k\in K$.  Counting the number of *distinct* such left cosets gives us the *index* $[K:H]$ of $H$ in $K$.

[The Reader is encouraged to prove that two such left cosets of $kH$ and $k'H$ are either equal or disjoint, which is why they partition $K$.  The same applies to *right cosets*, and the Reader is encouraged to find a bijection between these left cosets and right cosets, so that the count $[K:H]$ is the same whether we use one or the other choice to partition $K$.]

What it would mean for $n=[K:H]$ to be *finite* is that there are $n$ elements $k_1,\ldots,k_n \in K$ such that $K$ is the *disjoint* union $k_1H \cup \ldots \cup k_nH$.

Note that one of these parts must be the coset $H$, distinguished by being the coset that contains the identity $e$ of $K$ (and of $H$).  One easily shows that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $K$ exactly when each left coset is also a right coset of $H$.  It follows that subgroups of index $2$ will always be *normal* subgroups.